# Creating multiple instances of a dll object in Unity

Tags: c#, c++, audio, dll, multiple-instances

I'm creating a plugin for Unity which will link in an open source C++ music synthesis engine (http://rtcmix.org/). I am accessing it via a dll, which handles all the audio processing work. As the dll is an audio engine, it has a lot of complicated parts including many global variables. In order to be able to do synthesis on many different settings and different spatial points within a scene, I'd like to be able to create multiple objects, each with their own independent instance of the audio engine. Particularly, having access to multiple final sound outputs would allow for using Unity's spatialization by multiplying sample values.

However, this is not currently easy, and by default C# and Unity do not allow multiple instances of a dll (even if loaded from separate files). Even if I have two different gameobjects loading the dll, if one changes the value of a global variable it affects the other as well.

From what I can tell, dlls are not meant to be used this way, especially with the presence of global variables. Is there anyway I can do this with dlls. I have access to the source, is there some other method I might not be aware of to get this working in Unity?

Thanks so much in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: A dll should have no issues creating multiple instance of some C++ object through some kind of factory function.  But if you're using global variables, then by definition they're global and affect all instances.  If that's not what you want the globals need to be eliminated.

Comment: Sadly removing the global variables will be a lot of work (and even then will be quite hacky), and at that point I get the sense there may be more effective ways to use that time. Maybe a solution that doesn't even involve dlls. Thanks for confirming that global variables are the problem.